# New memory installed - anything else I should do in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ubuntu-10.04

I just upgraded my eee 1000 running Ubuntu 10.04 to 2Gb RAM.  It is being detected fine by BIOS and OS alike, but I wonder if I need to do anything else to take the most advantage of the extra memory.

For example, the swap space is configured to 1Gb.  Is there any point in repartitioning my hard drive so there is 2Gb of swap space?  Anything else I might consider?

Comment: Just leave it as it is.

Comment: Anything else I might want to do - e.g. any kind of profiling or anything that might have been done as part of the OS install process?  I know in Windows I wouldn't do anything, but not sure about Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I really doubt that any profiling as such happens during installation.

Answer (score 1):

Swap space is hard drive space used when memory is full. Getting more RAM means you need less swap, if anything. I suggest you just leave it though, unless you are running some really memory heavy stuff on it (why would you, it's a netbook!).

Comment: Yeah, but your swap partition needs to be larger than your RAM, because your memory is written to your swap partition when you hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do anything, any vaguely modern operating system (that is, anything released in the last decade or so) will automatically use the memory you've added (for 4 GB and above there are some considerations).

As for swap, you need swap when you run out of RAM.  The only time you want to ensure your swap is larger than your RAM is when you want to take kernel crash dumps for later analysis.  Otherwise you just need to ensure that RAM+SWAP is sufficient for your normal needs, which is should be if you've just added RAM.

Comment: But now I upgraded my swap space is half the size of my RAM.  Now I hope not to need swap space with what I use my Netbook for, but what happens if I need more than I have?

Comment: @dunxd - same as before, you run out ;)  If this didn't happen before then it shouldn't be a problem now since you've got more RAM than you did before.